# cannot update attribute within users model in custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the Gem Devise for users in my application. I added the role attribute within users that is set to nil. After I sign in, within the application controller I have a redirect that goes to a custom action within the users controller and view called binary_selection if `current_user.role = nil`. The code is below

application_controller.rb:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   if current_user.role.nil?  ## temporary solution
     #update_path(resource)
     binary_selection_path(resource)
   else
     root_path(resource)
   end
 end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
def binary_selection
  @user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user][:role])
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: "#{@user.name} was updated." }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

views/users/binary_selection.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_for @user, url: binary_selection_path(@user), html: { method: :patch } do |f|
 %><%= current_user %>
    <div class = "form-group">
      <%= f.label :role %>
      <%= f.text_field :role, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter wiki title", id: 'wiki_title' %>
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
      <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-success' ,id: 'wiki_submit'  %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  get "/users" => "users#binary_selection", as: 'binary_selection'
  resources :users

end
```

When I get redirected to the binary_selection view I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#binary_selection
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

where it highlights this line within the users controller:
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user][:role])

I also noticed it has this for the params on the error page:

```
 {"format"=>"13"}
```

Comment: It seems that some params you are expecting are missing. I suggest you `puts params` inside the `binary_selection` method to see what you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redirect your user after sign_in to the `binaray_selection_path`. This will result in a HTTP GET request. In your `users_controller` you try to get a attribute from the `params` that simple does not exist. There is no `params[:user]`, because the form was not sent yet.

You need to redirect the user to a page were the form is rendered.

I advise to read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running

Comment: I added a route and action called binary_selection_update and The form now displays, so thank you! I am now getting a new error though after I submit the form ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::RegistrationsController#update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- Your form is not submitting the values properly may be. So inspect your params in the binery select action.
- record#update_attributes doesn't take a single value, it accepts hash. So the proper code should be something like:

  ## rails version < 4

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

  ## in rails 4.*

  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

in controller make sure you have permitted the user parameters.